# Logging calls to Identity Provider with custom policies in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm trying to integrate a custom OpenID Connect Identity Provider in Azure AD B2C using custom policies.
However, after being redirected back from the IdP with an authorization code, the custom user flow fails with the following error (using MSAL.js):

```
login failure {"_error":"server_error","_errorDesc":"AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.\r\nCorrelation ID: 97809cc4-04e8-47a3-9263-de57260e7979\r\nTimestamp: 2019-07-18 15:47:32Z\r\n","_scopes":""}
```

I've enabled logging to Application Insights, but the only thing relevant I could find was:

```
  {
""Kind"": ""HandlerResult"",
""Content"": {
  ""Result"": true,
  ""RecorderRecord"": {
    ""Values"": [
      {
        ""Key"": ""SendErrorTechnicalProfile"",
        ""Value"": ""OAuth2ProtocolProvider""
      },
      {
        ""Key"": ""Exception"",
        ""Value"": {
          ""Kind"": ""Handled"",
          ""HResult"": ""80131500"",
          ""Message"": ""We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later."",
          ""Data"": {
            ""IsPolicySpecificError"": false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  ""Statebag"": {
    ""SE"": {
      ""c"": ""2019-07-18T13:46:21.1438143Z"",
      ""k"": ""SE"",
      ""v"": """",
      ""p"": true
    }
  }
}
},
```

Is there a way to log the actual network calls made to the Idp to see what is wrong? The Idp is not under my control, so I cannot log them there.

Comment: Most of the times IDPs use 302 redirects. You can see  those calls and response from Developer tools.

Comment: Indeed, but I cannot see the call to get the access token, or the call to the claims endpoint

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't find a way to log more info, I was able to solve my issue by using a reverse proxy to intercept all calls to the external IdP. This revealed that b2c was using `client_secret_post` to fetch the access token, while the IdP only supported `client_secret_basic`.

Comment: How did you actually solve the problem, is there way to configure B2C to use client_secret_basic?

Comment: @JussiPalo yes you can use `<Item Key="token_endpoint_auth_method">client_secret_basic</Item>` in the metadata of the technical profile of an OpenId Connect provider. I can't remember where I found this, as it isn't mentioned in the documentation, but I've created an issue to add it: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35662

Comment: Thanks, too bad it didn't have any effect on my LinkedIn and Google IdPs, still giving AADB2C90289 when configured via custom policy.

Comment: how did u put a reverse proxy between b2c and an IDP - point your custom policy to the proxy? or is there a hook to proxy all b2c calls?

Comment: @felickz indeed, pointed the custom policy to the proxy instead

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error/symptoms but my root cause was different.  In my case, my B2C policy was sending token requests using GET instead of POST and the IDP server only supported POST.  To correct that, I had to set the following in the metadata section of my OAuth2 technical profile.

```
<Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
```