# Azure AD B2C generic error with LinkedIn ClaimsProvider - AADB2C90289 We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have been trying to craft a UserJourney that will link a LinkedIn social account with an existing Local AAD B2C account.  I have used the following as guides:

- [Starter Pack - LinkedIn Provider](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/scenarios/linkedin-identity-provider)
- [Account Linking Policy Samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/account-linkage/policy)

When I configure in the Microsoft Account (which is OpenIdConnect) everything works perfectly, so I believe that I have the UserJourney parts correct.

When I attempt to use the LinkedIn OAuth2 ClaimsProvider it always fails with a generic error:

```
AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.
Correlation ID: 90f20acf-b725-405d-a3ac-120e5b559f6f
Timestamp: 2020-01-03 15:17:54Z
```

Things I have tried:

- Connecting Application Insights in Developer Mode - there is no tracing, logging or errors aside from the information above
- Creating a second LinkedIn App and switching credentials - same result
- Swapping in v1 and v2 `ClaimsEndpoint` urls
- Disabling all `OutputClaimsTransformations` and anything that seemed *calculated* - same result
- Creating a policy through the Portal (not custom) which allows me to login and creates a new account in the AAD; this is not what I need it to do, but does indicate that the credentials and setup of the LI App must be ok
- Tracing through network calls - I can see the response from LinkedIn being posted to `https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` with a `code` and a `state` argument so I assume the issue is in processing the response

As I mentioned, connecting the MSA-OIDC provider was fine, albeit that it is not OAuth2.  I presume, therefore, the issue is how I have the OAuth2 connection set up, but I can't spot the problem

Here's the material parts of my `ClaimsProvider`:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>linkedin.com</Domain>
    <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LinkedIn-OAUTH-Base">
            <DisplayName>LinkedIn</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="ProviderName">linkedin</Item>
                <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization</Item>
                <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me</Item>
                <!--<Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address)</Item>-->
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">oauth2_access_token</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormatName">format</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormat">json</Item>
                <Item Key="scope">r_emailaddress r_liteprofile</Item>
                <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                <Item Key="external_user_identity_claim_id">id</Item>
                <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
                <Item Key="ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens">true</Item>
                <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
                <Item Key="response_type">code</Item>
                <Item Key="client_id">0</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
                <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_LinkedInSecret" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LinkedIn-OAUTH-Link">
            <DisplayName>Link LinkedIn</DisplayName>
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">issuers</Item>
                <Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">linkedin.com</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <InputClaims />
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserIdToLink" PartnerClaimType="id" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerToLink" DefaultValue="linkedin.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdentityToLink" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AppendUserIdentityToLink" />
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="LinkedIn-OAUTH-Base" />
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
            <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnItemAbsenceInStringCollectionClaim</EnabledForUserJourneys>
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Note: I removed the `client_id` value but that is set in the real version.

Note 2: Also in the real version the `-Link` profile is in a different file to the `-Base` profile, but I don't think that's material to the problem.

If someone can help me spot the problem here I'd be grateful. I'm a bit stuck at this point.

Comment: See if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109533/logging-calls-to-identity-provider-with-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: Thanks @TonyJu - I was not able to resolve the issue, but I did completely remove LinkedIn, uploaded the files, re-added it and uploaded the files, and it mysteriously started to work.

Comment: Glad to hear that, you can add your solution as an answer.

Comment: I would do but I don’t think “turning it off and on again” really qualifies as a solution does it?

Comment: We got a non 200 response from linkedin as we redirected to their /authorization endpoint. Probably some issue there.